# Extension - Chrome native window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

it is possible to add/open Google Chrome native panel or window (something like firebug or like chrome dev tool) from extension level or maybe it is possible to add new tab to dev tool ?

Answer (score 0):

> it is possible to add/open Google Chrome native panel or window (something like firebug or like chrome dev tool) from extension level

No.

> or maybe it is possible to add new tab to dev tool ?

Yes. Declare a [devtools_page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html) in your extension's manifest, and use the [`chrome.devtools.panels`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.panels.html) API to "add a new tab".